# How I can display duplicate rows?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How I can display duplicated rows grupe by firstname and lastname but in different rows ?

I have the next code :

```
SELECT    LASTname, FIRSTname, COUNT(*) AS dupes  
FROM       TCPD_PERSONEL
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, 
HAVING      (COUNT(*) > 1);
```

when I run this appear :

```
lastname   firstname    dupes
Ion          Alin         2
```

but I want to appear something like this:

```
lastname  firstname      email 
Ion         Alin        alin@yahoo
Ion         Alin        ion@yahoo
```

Comment: Do U want to remove `GROUP BY`?

Comment: yes, I think if I have  GROUP BY, the rows how have different email doesn't display, and I want this thing

Comment: where lastname and first name are duplicate

Comment: what is the problem in using just `SELECT    LASTname, FIRSTname, COUNT(*) AS dupes  
FROM       TCPD_PERSONEL`

Answer (score 6):

Try this too

```
SELECT t1.LASTname,t1.FIRSTname,t1.email from TCPD_PERSONEL t1 inner join
(
SELECT    LASTname, FIRSTname, COUNT(*) AS dupes  
FROM       TCPD_PERSONEL
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, 
HAVING      (COUNT(*) > 1)
) t2 on t1.LASTname=t2.LASTname and t1.FIRSTname=t2.FIRSTname;
```

Comment: This answer has the correct general idea.  if there is a syntax error somewhere, you should be able to handle it.

Answer (score 2):

Use analytic functions:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM (SELECT p.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) as cnt  
      FROM TCPD_PERSONEL p
     ) p
WHERE cnt >= 2;
```

EDIT:

If the rows don't have complete duplicates (i.e., the email is different), then the following is perhaps the most efficient method:

```
select p.*
from TCPD_PERSONEL p
where exists (select 1
              from TCPD_PERSONEL p2
              where p2.firstname = p.firstname and p2.lastname = p.lastname and
                    p2.email <> p.email
             );
```

For performance, you want an index on `TCPD_PERSONEL(lastname, firstname, email)`.

Comment: I think this is dynamic language and I don't need something like this, and whatever in your answer missing email ...

Comment: @PopDaniela . . . I don't know what you mean by "dynamic language". This is not dynamic SQL.  This includes all columns in the table.  If you want a subset, just choose those.  This should also be among the most efficient way to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to join that query you have made with the same table again:

```
SELECT * FROM TCPD_PERSONEL 
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT    LASTname, FIRSTname, COUNT(*) AS dupes  
FROM       TCPD_PERSONEL
GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME
HAVING      (COUNT(*) > 1)
) x
ON x.LASTname = TCPD_PERSONEL.LASTname AND
x.FIRSTname = TCPD_PERSONEL.FIRSTname;
```

Comment: I have the next error : x.FIRSTname = TCPD_PERSONEL.FIRSTname
Error report -
Unknown Command

Comment: Sorry Daniela, I have made a syntax mistake (forgot to remove the semicolon from the temp query). I have just fixed it, please try it again

Comment: So, there is another syntax error that I carried from your code, as I have just copied and pasted it :) Remove the last comma in `GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME,` so it looks like `GROUP BY FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM tblInfo INNER JOIN (           
 SELECT    firstname, lastname, COUNT(*) AS temp  
 FROM       tblInfo
 GROUP BY lastname, firstname
 HAVING      (COUNT(*) > 1)
 ) x
 ON x. firstname = tblInfo. firstname AND
 x. lastname = tblInfo. lastname;
```

replace ‘tblInfo’ with ‘TCPD_PERSONEL’

Comment: I replaced  the name of the table but I have the next error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Are you using oracle or sql ?

Answer (score -1):

Looking at your code I think Distinct is the best option for you.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT  LASTname, FIRSTname,email 
FROM    TCPD_PERSONEL
```

Comment: No. The OP asked for the details where People have more than one email id